# Why doesn't my OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener get called?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

I have an `Example` class that implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.

```
public class Example implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

  public Example(Context cont) {
          this.context = cont;
          SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(cont);
          sharedPref.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
  }

  public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
          Log.d("TAG", "A preference has changed >>" + key);
  }
}
```

However, the `onSharedPreferenceChanged` method never gets called when I change a preference in the `SettingsActivity` hosting a fragment:

```
public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Load the preferences from an XML resource
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }

}
```

Why?

Comment: Where do you call your `Example` constructor?

Comment: In an activity, as an initialization of attribute:
private Example e = new Example(MyApp.getContext());